# Parallel processing not working when using execv

Tags: c, shell, unix, process, fork

So I am trying to parallel process, and use execv. The problem occurs is that when I parallel process, execv only runs in one child not both. I know that both child process's runs because of the printf statements about the pid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

  int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char input[100];
    char * path[15];
    path[0] = "/bin/";
    char str[200];
    FILE * fp;
    if (argc == 2) {
      if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    do {
      if (argc != 2) {
        printf("dash> ");
        fgets(input, 100, stdin);
      } else if (argc == 2) {
        if (fgets(input, 100, fp) == NULL)
          exit(0);
        printf(input);
      }
      input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
      char * token = strtok(input, " ");
      int c = 0;
      if ((strcmp(token, "exit") != 0) && (strcmp(token, "cd") != 0) && (strcmp(token, "path") != 0)) {
        do {
          if (path[c] == NULL) {
            printf("p error");
            break;
          }
          strcpy(str, path[c]);
          strcat(str, token);
          c++;
        } while (access(str, X_OK) == -1);
      }
      if (strcmp(token, "exit") == 0) {
        exit(0);
      } else if (strcmp(token, "cd") == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (chdir(token) == -1)
          printf("errorcd");
      } else if (strcmp(token, "path") == 0) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (path[counter] != NULL) {
          path[counter] = strtok(NULL, " ");
          counter++;
        }
      } else {
        char * myargs[15];
        char * par[15];
        myargs[0] = token;
        int counter = 0;
        int track = 0;
        int and = 1;
        while (myargs[counter] != NULL) // &&(strcmp(myargs[counter],">"))!=0){
        {
          counter++;
          myargs[counter] = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        int a = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int t = 0;
        // printf(myargs[i]);
        for (i = 0; i <= counter - 1; i++) {
          if (strcmp(myargs[i], "&") == 0)
            and++;
        }
        int temp = and + 1;
        // printf("No. %d",and);
        int rc[15];
        for (i = 0; i < and; i++) {
          a = 0;
          for (j = t; j <= counter - 1; j++) {
            par[a] = myargs[j];
            a++;
            if (strcmp(myargs[j], "&") == 0) {
              t = j + 1;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (and == 0)
            par[j + 1] = NULL;
          else
            par[j] = NULL;
          rc[i] = fork();
          if (rc[i] < 0) // fork failed
          {
            printf("Error");
            return 0;
          } else if (rc[i] == 0) // child process
          {
            printf("\nhello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
            if (j > 1) {
              if (strcmp(par[j - 2], ">") == 0) {
                int fd = open(par[j - 1], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
                dup2(fd, 1); // make stdout go to file
                dup2(fd, 2); // make stderr go to file - you may choose to not do this
                // or perhaps send stderr to another file
                // }
                par[counter - 2] = NULL;
              }
            }
            execv(str, par);
            printf("failed");
          }
        } // parent process
        int status;
        pid_t pid;

        while (temp > 0) {
          // waitpid(pid[i], 0, 0);
          pid = wait( & status);
          printf("Child with PID %ld exited with status 0x%x.\n", (long) pid, status);
          --temp; // TODO(pts): Remove pid from the pids array.
        }
      }
    } while (strcmp(input, "exit") != 0);
    return 0;
  }
```

I know this code is pretty bad, I have not coded in a while and am a little rusty. Anyway here is an example input and output.

```
dash> pwd & ls

hello, I am child (pid:40037)

hello, I am child (pid:40036)
/home/012/a/ax/axh161330/project1
Child with PID 40036 exited with status 0x0.
Child with PID 40037 exited with status 0x8b.
Child with PID -1 exited with status 0x8b.
```

As you can see, only one execv command executed (`pwd`), while the other never happened (`ls`). The first command will always work, while the 2nd will not happen.

Comment: Can you run your code through clang-format or something to clean it up? The apparently random indentation makes it almost impossible to actually read.

Comment: There are many problems with the code; a complete exegesis on the subject would take a very long time to write.  The code isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You'd not have code to handle commands like `exit`, `cd`, `path` in an MCVE, and the data would always come from a file (or always from standard input).  Your code to print the path only detects the end of the list of pointers by accident; you don't initialize them all to null pointers, so they're only accidentally null.  You could improve the diagnostics by printing the command in the child.

Comment: Your loop `for (i = 0; i <= counter - 1; i++)` would be better written as `for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)` — this is more idiomatic C and has the same effect.  However, what I've said is not guaranteed to be a solution to your problems.  Most likely, you need to see what the diagnostic outputs say.  There's a chance, for example, that your code is skipping `ls` altogether.  Also, is your `ls` in `/bin/ls` or is it in `/usr/bin/ls` (or are those the same because one of the directories is a symlink to the other)?

Comment: Error messages should be printed to standard error. After a call to one of the `exec*()` functions fails (by returning; there's no need to test the return value), report the error and exit the program (`exit()`, or one of the fast exits).  Don't let the errant child continue; it leads to confusion.

Comment: So, I know I missing a lot of error checking points, which I will do after I figure out the current problem. Your right about adding exit after exec. ls is a symlink directory so both user/bin and bin/ work. What diagnostic outputs do you mean?

Comment: btw `printf(input)` is one of the most known security bugs (format string vulnerability) - **always use `printf("%s", input)`** (or fputs, puts)

Comment: You print "hello, I am child" information, but it would be useful to have "and I'm about to exec the command xxxx with arguments yyyy zzzz" in the output.  I'm not prepared to try reading more of your code; I dislike the layout intensely and find it close to unreadable.  I do observe that if you want commands to execute in parallel, you can't afford to wait for each command to terminate before moving on to start the next.  I think your waiting code is in the wrong place, but I may be wrong.

Comment: the thing is it exits with 0x8b for me, that's -11/137 in human numbers btw. `SIGSEGV`. Time to start learning debugging.

Comment: `valgrind ./a.out` - null pointer dereference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , I added the print statement before the execv, but for some reason it only runs once, when calling 2 commands, even though if this printf statement is at the top of the child it runs both of them. Because of this I feel like maybe it is not waiting long enough for the 2nd command to run or something along those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adaptation of your code works, at least for `pwd & ls` as the command line.  One of the problems was that the loop to find the command path name was in the wrong place.  Another problem was that the `wait()` loop was in the wrong place.
Another problem was that the command arguments were not properly separated.

The code shows the printing (quite a lot of it) that I added to make sure I understood what was going on — and which highlighted some of the problems.

Source code (`exec29.c`):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char input[100];
    char *path[15];
    path[0] = "/bin/";
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    do
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            printf("dash> ");
            if (fgets(input, 100, stdin) == NULL)
                exit(0);
        }
        else if (argc == 2)
        {
            if (fgets(input, 100, fp) == NULL)
                exit(0);
        }

        input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", input);
        char *token = strtok(input, " ");

        int temp = 0;
        if (strcmp(token, "exit") == 0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "cd") == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            if (chdir(token) == -1)
                fprintf(stderr, "error: cd %s\n", token);
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "path") == 0)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (path[counter] != NULL)
            {
                path[counter] = strtok(NULL, " ");
                if (path[counter] != NULL)
                    printf("PATH: %s\n", path[counter]);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            char *myargs[15];
            char *par[15];
            myargs[0] = token;
            int counter = 0;
            int n_cmds = 1;
            while (myargs[counter] != NULL)
            {
                counter++;
                myargs[counter] = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                printf("%d: [[%s]]\n", i, myargs[i]);

            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(myargs[i], "&") == 0)
                    n_cmds++;
            }
            temp = n_cmds;
            printf("Num commands: %d\n", n_cmds);

            int t = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n_cmds; i++)
            {
                int a = 0;
                for (int j = t; j < counter; j++)
                {
                    if (strcmp(myargs[j], "&") == 0)
                    {
                        t = j + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    par[a++] = myargs[j];
                }
                par[a] = NULL;
                int rc = fork();
                if (rc < 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: fork failed\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (rc == 0)
                {
                    char str[200];
                    printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int)getpid());
                    int c = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        if (path[c] == NULL)
                        {
                            fprintf(stderr, "path error - no PATH left\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        strcpy(str, path[c++]);
                        strcat(str, par[0]);
                    } while (access(str, X_OK) == -1);
                    printf("Cmd: [[%s]]\n", str);

                    char **args = par;
                    while (*args != NULL)
                        printf("[[%s]]\n", *args++);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    execv(str, par);
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed\n", str);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
        }

        while (temp > 0)
        {
            int status;
            pid_t pid = wait(&status);
            printf("%d: Child with PID %ld exited with status 0x%.4x.\n",
                   (int)getpid(), (long)pid, status);
            --temp;
        }

    } while (strcmp(input, "exit") != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Given a file `test-exec` containing:

```
pwd & ls
pwd -P & ls -l
```

I got the example output (`exec29 test-exec`):

```
pwd & ls
0: [[pwd]]
1: [[&]]
2: [[ls]]
Num commands: 2
hello, I am child (pid:4247)
Cmd: [[/bin/pwd]]
[[pwd]]
hello, I am child (pid:4248)
Cmd: [[/bin/ls]]
[[ls]]
/Users/jleffler/soq/so-5225-1783
4246: Child with PID 4247 exited with status 0x0000.
exec23.c    exec29      exec29.c    exec29.dSYM exec97.c    makefile    test-exec   test-exec-2
4246: Child with PID 4248 exited with status 0x0000.
pwd -P & ls -l
0: [[pwd]]
1: [[-P]]
2: [[&]]
3: [[ls]]
4: [[-l]]
Num commands: 2
hello, I am child (pid:4249)
Cmd: [[/bin/pwd]]
[[pwd]]
[[-P]]
hello, I am child (pid:4250)
Cmd: [[/bin/ls]]
[[ls]]
[[-l]]
/Users/jleffler/soq/so-5225-1783
4246: Child with PID 4249 exited with status 0x0000.
total 80
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  3722 Sep 10 20:43 exec23.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  9644 Sep 10 21:41 exec29
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  4054 Sep 10 21:41 exec29.c
drwxr-xr-x  3 jleffler  staff    96 Sep 10 21:05 exec29.dSYM
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  4549 Sep 10 21:45 exec97.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   163 Sep 10 21:41 makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff    24 Sep 10 21:47 test-exec
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff    34 Sep 10 21:38 test-exec-2
4246: Child with PID 4250 exited with status 0x0000.
```

I did remove the code that seemed to be related to I/O redirection; I didn't remove the code related to `cd`, `exit`, or `path`, but neither did I test them.

One minor, obscure point: the standard header `<iso646.h>` defines a macro `and` that expands to `&&`.  It's best not to use any of the names from that header as variable names, though it is rare indeed that people use the header in C (but the names are reserved as 'alternative representations' in C++).

Comment: Thanks, yea I figured it out on Monday, The path was wrong, being the problem, so when i fixed it, it worked.